# DotConnect inefficient boolean compare SQL generation

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, dotconnect

One of my entities has a boolean property. One of the linq queries filters on this property.

```
context.Items.Where(one => one.BoolProperty == true)
```

When I look at the generated SQL code, then the query is translated to

```
... WHERE "Extend1".BOOL_PROPERTY <> 0
```

This is obviously a problem, as the database does not take the index but makes a full table access.

We are using .Net 4.6, Entity Framework 6, DevArt 8.5 and Oracle 12. The boolean field in Oracle is a Number(1,0)

Comment: A Bitmap Index will work in this case. However Bitmap indexes are not always appropriate. see [Bitmap Index vs. B-tree Index: Which and When?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sharma-indexes-093638.html). Did you try `Where(one => one.BoolProperty != false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the following option in your code:

```
config.QueryOptions.TrueValueNumber = TrueValueNumber.One;
```

For more information, refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?QueryOptions.html .

Comment: Wow, I was sure that there is a config option to override this behavior! But I never would had guessed that it's TrueValueNumber. Thanks